# Can someone provide me a specification of 32 bit BMP image format?

Tags: 32-bit, bmp, specifications

My application have some problem on opening 32bit BMP images.
some image has alpha channel  and with certain value, but window image viewer, picasa photoshop seems ignore the alpha channel.
how can I know whether I should take the alpha channel into account.

So I need a specification of 32bit BMP Image. Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also in Wikipedia: [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

Answer (score 3):

The ultimate documentation for the BMP format comes from the authors of it - Microsoft. Read it at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921550.aspx).

Comment: Read it carefully. It's both. BMP format is defined through these structures.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wotsit.org/ has the answer:

(Warning for popups when visiting following link)
http://www.fortunecity.com/skyscraper/windows/364/bmpffrmt.html