# About BMP file. How can i write/change a pixel color? (in C)

Tags: c, memory, file, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to change a pixel from a picture (format bmp, 24 bits).

I have this 3 structures:

for file header:

```
#pragma pack(2)
typedef struct {
unsigned short int typeID;
unsigned int size;
unsigned short int reserved1, reserved2;
unsigned int offset;
}BITMAPFILEHEADER;
#pragma pack(0)
```

for information header:

```
typedef struct {
unsigned int headerSize;
signed int widthPixel, heightPixel;
unsigned short int colorPlanes;
unsigned short int bitsPerPixel;
unsigned int compressionMethod;
unsigned int imagesize;
signed int xResolution, yResolution; // pixel per meter
unsigned int nbColor;
unsigned int importantColor;
}BITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

for RGB color:

```
typedef struct {
unsigned char blue;
unsigned char green;
unsigned char red;
unsigned char reserved;
} RGBCOLOR;
```

Then the main code:

```
int main(void) {
BITMAPFILEHEADER fileHeader;
BITMAPINFOHEADER infoHeader;
FILE *inFileImage = NULL;

unsigned char *pBitsData = NULL;
int rowSize     = 0;
int nImageSize  = 0;


inFileImage = fopen("panda.bmp", "r+");
if (inFileImage == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open image");
    return 0;
}

fread(&fileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inFileImage);
rewind(inFileImage);
pBitsData = (unsigned char *)calloc( fileHeader.size, sizeof(unsigned char) );

if( NULL == pBitsData )
{
    printf("NO memory!!!!!\n");
}
else
{
    fread(pBitsData, fileHeader.size * sizeof(unsigned char), 1, inFileImage);

    memcpy(&fileHeader,pBitsData,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));

    printf("Type ID: %x\n", fileHeader.typeID);
    printf("File size: %d\n", fileHeader.size);
    printf("Offset: %d\n", fileHeader.offset);
    printf("**********************\n");

    memcpy(&infoHeader, (pBitsData + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

    printf("Header size: %u\n", infoHeader.headerSize);
    printf("Width: %d\n", infoHeader.widthPixel);
    printf("Height: %d\n", infoHeader.heightPixel);
    printf("Nb planes: %d\n", infoHeader.colorPlanes);
    printf("Bits per pixel: %d\n", infoHeader.bitsPerPixel);
    printf("Compression method: %u\n", infoHeader.compressionMethod);
    printf("Image size: %u\n", infoHeader.imagesize);
    printf("Horizontal pixel per metre: %d\n", infoHeader.xResolution);
    printf("Vertical pixel per metre: %d\n", infoHeader.yResolution);
    printf("Number color in color table: %u\n", infoHeader.nbColor);
    printf("Color important count: %u\n", infoHeader.importantColor);
    printf("**********************\n");

    rowSize = ((infoHeader.bitsPerPixel * infoHeader.widthPixel + 31) / 32) * 4;
    printf("Row Size: %d\n", rowSize);
    nImageSize = rowSize * abs(infoHeader.heightPixel);
    printf("Pixel Array Size: %d\n", nImageSize);
    printf("**********************\n");

    RGBCOLOR* pixelData = (RGBCOLOR*)(pBitsData + fileHeader.offset);

    // M is define with the value 5 - the 5 pixel from image
    printf("Pixel %x, %x, %x\n", pixelData[M].blue, pixelData[M].green, pixelData[M].red);

    //fseek(inFileImage, fileHeader.offset, SEEK_CUR);
    //fread(pixelData, sizeof(RGBCOLOR), 1, inFileImage);

    pixelData[M].red    = 0x00;
    pixelData[M].blue   = 0xef;
    pixelData[M].green  = 0x00;

    //memcpy((pBitsData + fileHeader.offset), &pixelData, sizeof(RGBCOLOR));     // <= here seems to be my problem
    //fwrite(pixelData, sizeof(RGBCOLOR), 1, inFileImage);   // how can i copy to image from a memory

    printf("Pixel %x, %x, %x\n", pixelData[M].blue, pixelData[M].green, pixelData[M].red);  
}


fclose(inFileImage);
if(NULL != pBitsData)
{
   free(pBitsData);
}

return 0;
```

}

I want to change the 5th pixel from image (one of this: blue->red, green->blue, etc).
Can you show me where do i have mistakes in my code? And how can i change to work correctly my code? Thx

Edit:

instead of

```
RGBCOLOR* pixelData = (RGBCOLOR*)(pBitsData + fileHeader.offset);

    // M is define with the value 5 - the 5 pixel from image
    printf("Pixel %x, %x, %x\n", pixelData[M].blue, pixelData[M].green, pixelData[M].red);

    //fseek(inFileImage, fileHeader.offset, SEEK_CUR);
    //fread(pixelData, sizeof(RGBCOLOR), 1, inFileImage);

    pixelData[M].red    = 0x00;
    pixelData[M].blue   = 0xef;
    pixelData[M].green  = 0x00;

    //memcpy((pBitsData + fileHeader.offset), &pixelData, sizeof(RGBCOLOR));     // <= here seems to be my problem
    //fwrite(pixelData, sizeof(RGBCOLOR), 1, inFileImage);   // how can i copy to image from a memory

    printf("Pixel %x, %x, %x\n", pixelData[M].blue, pixelData[M].green,       pixelData[M].red);
```

if i write

```
    RGBCOLOR img;
    fseek(inFileImage, fileHeader.offset, SEEK_SET);
    img.blue    = 0x00;
    img.green   = 0x00;
    img.red     = 0xff;
    fwrite(&img, sizeof(RGBCOLOR), 1, inFileImage);
```

This will change the first pixel. But i want to copy in memory, and from there to change the pixel.

Comment: What does the code currently do?

Comment: Now, the code just show information about file header, information header.  Here: pixelData[M].blue   = 0xef; is writing the blue pixel with the value 0xef in memory. I want this to be written in the bmp file. I've tried with fwrite/memcpy to file, but without success.

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is. Is the pixel not changed? If so, how does the output differ from what you're expecting? You should probably start by adding some code to either write the modified bitmap back to disk, or display it on screen.

Comment: _"without success"_ is not a good description. You need to be a lot more detailed than that.

Comment: btw, if `M = 5` aren't you changing the **6th** pixel?

Comment: M = 5 is just an example

Comment: @ghergut - don't forget, if the heightPixel member of your BITMAPINFO structure is positive, you have a **bottom-up** image, i.e The scanlines are stored bottom-line first. Your example will change the **bottom**-left pixel unless heightPixel is a negative number. See the _Remarks_ section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I use MinGW, so you'll need to change the `#pragma`s used for structure alignment.
Here's an all-in-one source that will

- read an image
- change a specified pixel
- output the modified image to a new file

I haven't bothered with any error checking in the interests of brevity. I've tested it with a 24/32 bit images. It doesn't output a valid image when used with 32 bit images.

First, here's the before and after images. The image itself is 2x2 pixels, I've just shown it larger here for the sake of visibility.

**Before:**

[image] [image]

**After:**

[image] [image]

If you have a close look, you can see that the only byte different between the 2 images is the one at 0x3E in the file. We've changed a red pixel (00 00 FF) to a purple one (FF 00 FF). Since the image is a bottom-up one, the first 3 bytes of the pixel data are for the yellow pixel, the next 3 are for the blue one, 2 bytes of padding follows, then we have 3 for red, 3 for green and another 2 padding bytes.

Here's the code that made the change:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#ifndef WORD
 #define WORD unsigned short
#endif

#ifndef DWORD
 #define DWORD unsigned long
#endif

#ifndef BYTE
 #define BYTE unsigned char
#endif

#ifndef LONG
 #define LONG long
#endif


#define minGW  1

#ifdef minGW
    #pragma pack(push,2)
#endif
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
    WORD    bfType;
    DWORD   bfSize;
    WORD    bfReserved1;
    WORD    bfReserved2;
    DWORD   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER,*LPBITMAPFILEHEADER,*PBITMAPFILEHEADER;
#ifdef minGW
    #pragma pack(pop)
#endif

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER{
    DWORD   biSize;
    LONG    biWidth;
    LONG    biHeight;
    WORD    biPlanes;
    WORD    biBitCount;
    DWORD   biCompression;
    DWORD   biSizeImage;
    LONG    biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG    biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD   biClrUsed;
    DWORD   biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER,*LPBITMAPINFOHEADER,*PBITMAPINFOHEADER;

typedef struct tagRGBQUAD
{
    BYTE    rgbBlue;
    BYTE    rgbGreen;
    BYTE    rgbRed;
    BYTE    rgbReserved;
} RGBQUAD,*LPRGBQUAD;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFO
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
    RGBQUAD bmiColors[1];
} BITMAPINFO,*LPBITMAPINFO,*PBITMAPINFO;

typedef struct tagBITMAP
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER    bmInfo;
    unsigned char       *pBits;
} BITMAP, *PBITMAP;

PBITMAP readBitmapFile(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;
    PBITMAP result;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER fileHeader;
    BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

    fread(&fileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fp);

    fread(&bmpInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO), 1, fp);

    fseek(fp, fileHeader.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);
    unsigned char *pBits = (unsigned char *)calloc(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, sizeof(unsigned char) );
    fread(pBits, sizeof(char), bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    result = (PBITMAP) calloc(1, sizeof(*result) );
    memcpy(&result->bmInfo, &bmpInfo, sizeof(bmpInfo) );
    result->pBits = pBits;
    return result;
}

void saveBitmapFile(const char *filename, PBITMAP img)
{
    FILE *fp;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER fileHeader;
    memset(&fileHeader, 0, sizeof(fileHeader));
    fileHeader.bfType = 0x4d42; //'BM'
    fileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
    fileHeader.bfSize = fileHeader.bfOffBits + (img->bmInfo.biSizeImage);

    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    fwrite(&fileHeader, sizeof(fileHeader), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&img->bmInfo, sizeof(img->bmInfo), 1, fp);
    fwrite(img->pBits, 1, img->bmInfo.biSizeImage, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}


void myPixel(int x, int y, char r, char g, char b, PBITMAP image)
{
    unsigned char *ptrToPixel;
    int rowSize = ((image->bmInfo.biBitCount * image->bmInfo.biWidth + 31) / 32) * 4;
    int curRow, bytesPerPixel;
    if (image->bmInfo.biHeight < 0)
    {
        curRow = y;
    }
    else if (image->bmInfo.biHeight > 0)
    {
        curRow = (image->bmInfo.biHeight-1) - y;
    }
    bytesPerPixel = image->bmInfo.biBitCount / 8;
    ptrToPixel = (curRow * rowSize) + (x*bytesPerPixel) + image->pBits;

    ptrToPixel[0] = b;
    ptrToPixel[1] = g;
    ptrToPixel[2] = r;
}

int main()
{
    PBITMAP inImage = readBitmapFile("colorTile.bmp");
    myPixel(0,0, 255,0,255, inImage);
    saveBitmapFile("colorTileOut.bmp", inImage);
}
```

EDIT:
After reading [Can someone provide me a specification of 32 bit BMP image format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426032/can-someone-provide-me-a-specification-of-32-bit-bmp-image-format) and https://forums.adobe.com/message/3272950#3272950 it seemed apparent that 32 bit bitmaps were using a V3 header - a header that includes 4 longs to specify the bitmask of each of the 4 channels. I've subsequently modified both the `saveBitmapFile` and `myPixel` routines and can confirm that the code now appears to function correctly with 32 bit bitmaps too.

```
void saveBitmapFile(const char *filename, PBITMAP img)
{
    FILE *fp;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER fileHeader;
    unsigned long maskArray[] = {0xFF000000, 0x00FF0000, 0x0000FF00, 0x000000FF};
    memset(&fileHeader, 0, sizeof(fileHeader));
    fileHeader.bfType = 0x4d42; //'BM'
    fileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
    if (img->bmInfo.biBitCount == 32)
        fileHeader.bfOffBits += sizeof(maskArray);
    fileHeader.bfSize = fileHeader.bfOffBits + (img->bmInfo.biSizeImage);

    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    fwrite(&fileHeader, sizeof(fileHeader), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&img->bmInfo, sizeof(img->bmInfo), 1, fp);
    if (img->bmInfo.biBitCount == 32)
        fwrite(&maskArray, sizeof(long), 4, fp);
    fwrite(img->pBits, 1, img->bmInfo.biSizeImage, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void myPixel(int x, int y, char r, char g, char b, PBITMAP image)
{
    unsigned char *ptrToPixel;
    int rowSize = ((image->bmInfo.biBitCount * image->bmInfo.biWidth + 31) / 32) * 4;
    int curRow, bytesPerPixel;
    if (image->bmInfo.biHeight < 0)
    {
        curRow = y;
    }
    else if (image->bmInfo.biHeight > 0)
    {
        curRow = (image->bmInfo.biHeight-1) - y;
    }
    bytesPerPixel = image->bmInfo.biBitCount / 8;
    ptrToPixel = (curRow * rowSize) + (x*bytesPerPixel) + image->pBits;

    if (image->bmInfo.biBitCount == 24)
    {
        ptrToPixel[0] = b;
        ptrToPixel[1] = g;
        ptrToPixel[2] = r;
    }

    else if (image->bmInfo.biBitCount == 32)
    {
//        ptrToPixel[0] = a;
        ptrToPixel[1] = b;
        ptrToPixel[2] = g;
        ptrToPixel[3] = r;
    }
}
```